# Azure RHEL7.x NIC Teaming or Bonding

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rhel, switching, nic

I am trying to accomplish higher internal RHEL VM to VM bandwidth for large file SINGLE JOB use. 10Gbps is not enough.

In Azure it is possible to Team NIC's in Windows. Is it possible to Team or Bond NICs in Azure with RHEL7.x? Note that the "switch" is un-configurable so no LACP ect. it has to support independent mode(RFC?) as far as I am aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, current release does not support Team and Bond NICs in Azure with RHEL7.X. Because the internet-facing IP is only support on the "Primary" NIC, and the public IP resource managed by the Azure Platform, so we can't change public IP address to another NIC by Team and Bond in Azure.

More information about multiple VM NICs, refer to the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/multiple-vm-nics-and-network-virtual-appliances-in-azure/).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.